# PHP: How can a variable be equal to 1 and -1 at the same time?

Tags: php

I have a variable that reports as 1, but when I test `$success == -1`, that evaluates to true as well.  How can this be??

```
$fn = FCPATH.'webservices/debug/DEBUG2.txt';
file_put_contents( $fn, '$success = '.$success."\n", FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents( $fn, '$success == -1 : '.($success == -1)."\n", FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents( $fn, '$success == 1 : '.($success == 1)."\n", FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents( $fn, '1 == -1 : '.(1 == -1)."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Output:

```
$success = 1
$success == -1 : 1
$success == 1 : 1
1 == -1 :
```

Any idea what's going on here??  I am in bizarro world here...

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out, so thought I'd try to be the first to answer... ;-)

I decided to print `gettype($succes)`, and that reported `boolean`.  So, it seems that the test is coercing the type to boolean before comparing, and for booleans, anything non-zero is `true`.

And, when converting boolean to string, php generates a 1, so it's easy to mistake it for an integer.

Short answer, `(true == -1)` is true.

Comment: Hence, use `===`.